# AWS CLI V2 installation issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I encountered a problem while trying to install AWS CLI v2 on Ubuntu 22.04 running on WSL. Here's the error message I received:

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~/Python-3.11.1$ aws --version

Fatal error condition occurred in /tmp/pip-install-90cp_aq0/awscrt_d52d3579cb5e4eb1a9ee6f8f288622f3/crt/aws-c-common/source/allocator.c:187: num != 0 && size != 0 Exiting Application ################################################################################ Stack trace: ################################################################################
 /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/_awscrt.abi3.so(aws_backtrace_print+0x4d) [0x7f74e1d4de6d] /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/_awscrt.abi3.so(aws_fatal_assert+0x44) [0x7f74e1d41cc4] /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/_awscrt.abi3.so(aws_mem_calloc+0xee) 
[0x7f74e1d40f7e] /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/_awscrt.abi3.so(aws_s3_platform_info_loader_new+0x88) 
[0x7f74e1c975f8] /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/_awscrt.abi3.so(aws_s3_library_init+0x52) [0x7f74e1c8ed52] /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/_awscrt.abi3.so(PyInit__awscrt+0x10b) 
[0x7f74e1c8600b] /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x2ac245) 
[0x7f74eb0ac245] /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/dist/libpython3.11.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1f5) [0x7f74eb07b2a5] aws() [0x40332d] aws() [0x403675] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) 
[0x7f74eb801d90] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) 
[0x7f74eb801e40] aws() [0x401d11] Aborted
```

If anyone has encountered this issue before and found a solution, please share your insights. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: how did you try to install?

Comment: curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install

Comment: Its a bug in aws cli -> https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/8320

Comment: Thank you @AlbinPaul for the information

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you can install the previous version with:

curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.13.33.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install --update